# Intel igb driver building with checkinstall

Tags: debian, nic, intel, checkinstall

How to properly compile the latest Intel igb driver (4.1.2) with checkinstall ? When I am trying to do this I got following error:

```
*checkinstall -D
root@debian:~/igb-4.1.2/src# ========================= Installation results ===========================
-bash: =========================: command not found
root@debian:~/igb-4.1.2/src# make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/build SUBDIRS=/root/igb-4.1.2/src modules
  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.
  CC [M]  /root/igb-4.1.2/src/igb_main.o
In file included from <command-line>:0:0:
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common/include/linux/kconfig.h:4:32: fatal error: generated/autoconf.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[4]: *** [/root/igb-4.1.2/src/igb_main.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [_module_/root/igb-4.1.2/src] Error 2
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64'
make: *** [default] Error 2
****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.
Cleaning up...OK*
```

What's that ?? "Make install" working fine, but I need it in .deb package. Somebody could help me resolve this problem ?

My specs:

```
uname -r
3.2.0-4-amd64


lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 (wheezy)
Release:        7.0
Codename:       wheezy
```

Comment: Powerthrash, welcome to Server Fault! What part of `Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.` do you fail to understand?

Comment: I tried this, still the same issue...

Comment: And igb required only kernel headers, not kernel source itself...

Answer (score 1):

you probably have the buggy version of checkinstall.
I've cloned the buggy version also direct from official git repository:
git clone http://checkinstall.izto.org/checkinstall.git
This version seems to process Makefile of linux-headers in other /strange/ way (seems, it tries to compile whole kernel).

If I used version of checkinstall from ubuntu repository, everything goes well ...
http://launchpadlibrarian.net/133950593/checkinstall_1.6.2-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb

Give it a try :-)

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can update your kernel header.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64
```

ref: http://pkgs.org/debian-wheezy/debian-main-amd64/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64_3.2.41-2_amd64.deb.html